# My script not working in IE 10 and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script which works in IE10 compatibility mode and below but fails in IE 10 and also it does not work in Chrome.

Can some one please look at it and let me know what should I change to make it work?

I have a group of dropdown lists which gets its values from a source and at the very last I have 2 Dropdown with a select option .. when both of these are selected to something using the below I create another Table row and dropdown boxes with select as the default selected value .. What is happening is it is taking the first option in the dropdown list and making it selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var hiddenCounterID = $('input[id$="HiddenCounter"]').attr('id');
    var hiddenIDUse = '#' + hiddenCounterID;
    $('.MainTable1').on('change', 'tr:last select', function () {
        var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        if ($tr.find('select :first').val() !== 'Select' && $tr.find('select :last').val() !== 'Select')
        $tr.clone(true).find('select').each(function () {
            $(this).val('').attr('name', function (_, name) {
                return 'ddlListItemVal_' + i;
            });
        }).end().insertAfter($tr);
        i++;
        $('#' + hiddenCounterID).val(i);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with html.

Comment: does it throw any errors? Be specific...

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/JXsJb/1/

Comment: Sorry about that guys ..here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x5PX5/ ..so what's happening is when you select the lat options when u select both the select dropdowns in IE10compatibility and below it created a new tr and makes the select option as default but in Chrome and IE10 it creates a new TR but makes the first item present in dropdown as the default selected item.

Comment: Actually, you are creating a new table row and using '' as the selected value, which is supposed to select the first item in the select list.

Comment: But it's working properly in IE9 and below..can you please tell me what do I need to change.

Comment: He just told you what's causing the behavior you don't want.

Comment: BTW, your code doesn't work in IE 9 either, just IE 8 and below.  It also doesn't work in firefox, chrome, and likely doesn't work in safari, or opera either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x5PX5/2/

Change trying to set the values of the new selects from `''` to `'Select'` so it works in standards compliant browsers.